# 20.04, HP Pavilion gaming 15 laptop, touchpad not working

Tags: touchpad, laptop, 20.04, hp, hp-touchpad

In my new laptop HP Pavilion gaming 15 in ubuntu 20.04 touchpad not worked :( I install last kernel, but it not resolving this issue

```
$ uname -a
Linux tln-hp 5.6.14-050614-generic #202005200733 SMP Wed May 20 07:38:05 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ FH 2.4G Mouse                             id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru           id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ JQ-BT (AVRCP)                             id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

dmesg output here: https://gofile.io/d/7m3QFr

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, and researching a long time, in a very old forum I found this

You have to edit the following file:

```
/etc/default/grub
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nopnp=1 quiet splash"
```

And then place in the terminal. Regards

```
sudo modprobe -r psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse proto=imps
```

This worked for me, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you very match, @Ale, I did as you wrote above, but it not helped me :( I have 2 strings in /etc/default/grub:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.kbdreset=1 quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="i8042.nopnp=1 quiet splash"

I tried to comment first - it's not taked effect...

Answer (score 0):

The following solved the issue for me

From the Terminal, run the following as root or sudo:

```
add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
```

This adds the repository for additional drivers for Nvidia, which appears to be the cause of the problem with the touchpad.

Then run as root or sudo:

```
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

You may see the following output:

> All the available drivers are already installed.

Open "Software & Updates" and select the latest relevant driver, or the recommended driver.

Run the following (I've included sudo for the sake of simplicity):

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
```

Reboot your system.

Comment: you may try this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/585681/ubuntu-20-04-upgrades-breaks-keyboard-mouse/763179#763179 and do some experiments with modules loaded at boot time ... few are missing (i2c-hid etc.) , some can have negative effects by being active.