# Touchpad is not working at all

Tags: 20.04, mouse, touchpad, hp, input-devices

I have an HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15-ec0xxx with Ubuntu 20.04, and its ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad is not working

The touchpad shows up in xinput list, and so does my USB optical mouse, the ID of my mouse (9) is lower than that of the touchpad (12). I think this means that my mouse is registered before the touchpad.
Touchpad also shows up in /cat/proc/input/devices.

I have tried the following solutions -and more I cannot find- in vain: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854798 
[20.04, HP Pavilion gaming 15 laptop, touchpad not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243794/20-04-hp-pavilion-gaming-15-laptop-touchpad-not-working) 
[Elantech Touchpad not working on Ubuntu 16.04 and Arch Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763584/elantech-touchpad-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-and-arch-linux) 
https://www.maketecheasier.com/fix-touchpad-not-working-linux/ (Have installed all the packages mentioned)

This is the output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6f1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:b00c Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Bluetooth Radio
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Looking at the long history of that question, either on Linux Mint or Debian (and other distros) it seems that your piece of hardware will not work on Ubuntu... Your investigations are correct, but you'd probably won't find solutions in older versions, since the kernel has changed since then

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `lsusb`? This will show the device ID, which can then be used to check for compatibility on Linux-Hardware.org

Comment: I have added the output of `lsusb` @matigo

Comment: What do you suggest @kanehekili? Is there any way to find out which kernel version supports my hardware?

Comment: Also, the touchpad did work a very few times. But this was a while back.
@kanehekili

Comment: There does not seem to be a touchpad enabled on your notebook. Some HP notebooks will let you enable/disable the touchpad by double-tapping the pad in the upper-left corner. Alternatively, there could be a keyboard shortcut like [Fn]+[Key] (a key with a blue icon that looks something like a touchpad).

Comment: My laptop does not have an [Fn]+[Key] shortcut. And double-tapping on the top left of the touchpad also does not work

Comment: My touchpad device name is no longer displayed in the output of xinput list @matigo

Comment: If the device isn't showing up anywhere and you're unable to re-enable it, then you may have a broken touchpad 

Comment: Touchpad works on Windows; dualbooting